# Making v-treeview the same height as a row in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I have a CodePen at https://codepen.io/james-hudson3010/pen/gOPEbvx

What I currently see is:

[image: Generated Content]

I would like to know what I need to change so the red area is covered by the yellow area...the yellow area is the area of the v-treeview component. The red area only appears when it is shorter than the content in the left column.

I have tried setting various height's to 100%, but I am missing something.

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container class="green lighten-5" fluid>
      <v-row no-gutters dense style="flex-wrap: nowrap" class="align-stretch primary lighten-3">
          <v-col class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0" style="flex-basis: 20em;">
              <v-card flat class="green lighten-3" style="height: 100%;">
                
                  Some Column Context<br>
                  Some Column Context<br>
                  Some Column Context<br>
                  Some Column Context<br>
                  Some Column Context<br>
                  Some Column Context<br>
                  Some Column Context<br>                
                
              </v-card>
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="flex-grow-2" style="background-color: red;">

            <v-tabs
                v-model="tab"
                background-color="primary lighten-3"
                style="height: 100%"
            >                

                <v-tab
                    v-for="tabName in tabNames"
                    :key="tabName.id"
                    :href="`#${tabName}`"
                >

                    {{ tabName }}
                  
                </v-tab>

                <v-tab-item
                    v-for="tabName in tabNames"
                    :key="tabName.id"
                    :value="`${tabName}`"
                    class="yellow lighten-4"
                    style="height: 100%"                            
                >

                    <v-container fluid style="height: 100%">
                        <v-row dense col no-gutters class = "rowborder">
                            <v-col cols = "12">
                                <v-treeview dense activatable :items="childrenForTab">
                                    <template v-slot:label="{ item }">
                                        <span class="treeItem">{{ item.name }}</span>
                                    </template>
                                </v-treeview>
                            </v-col>
                        </v-row>
                    </v-container>

                </v-tab-item>           

            </v-tabs>             
            
          </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
  data() 
  {
    return {
      tabNames: [ 'a', 'b' ],
      tab: null,     
    }
  },
  
  computed: 
  {
    childrenForTab()
    {
      if ( this.tab == 'a' )
      {
        return [
          { name: '1' },
          { name: '2' },
          { name: '3' },
          { name: '4' }         
        ]    
      }
      else
      {
        return [
          { name: '1' },
          { name: '2' }      
        ]           
      }
    }
  }
  
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this in your CSS:

```
.v-tabs {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.v-window.v-item-group {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.v-window__container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I am curious. Are solutions such as this a recommended practice or is this considered something hackish?

Comment: My next question would be ... if there were two <v-tabs> components visible and one wanted this style to only apply to the one but not the other, is that possible? I tried setting an id="myID" on the <v-tabs> and doing #myID.v-tabs {}, but it is unclear to me how to specify the children of the v-tabs and apply the needed styles to them explicitly.

Comment: For each v-tabs, you add an `id` (`id="a"`), which corresponds to the names of the tab you specified in `tabNames`.
https://gyazo.com/f22b70c8462057e5bfc7712aaecdb6fe

Comment: Great. 

While this does answer the question, when I tried to apply to to a regular vue app, it appears that the styles for .v-window.v-item-group & .v-window__container are being stomped on and do not get applied.